# Not showing any compilation in iTunes Connect for TestFlight

Tags: ios, xcode, app-store-connect

I'm trying to use TestFligiht, to distribute my iOS app on beta testers.

I've created the app, I've choosing the correct bundleID, etc on main configuration in iTunes Connect. But no compilation is showing in "TestFlight" section.

In Xcode I have configured the correct certificate, and I've did Product -> Archive.

But still doesn't appearing any compilation. :(

Any idea for this?

Comment: Did you got .ipa file of your app? or still it's archiving?

Comment: Yes, I have .ipa file!

Comment: Did you uploaded to itunes?

Comment: No, I didn't know I have to do it. How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

Once you archived your source code.After you have to upload your .IPA file to iTunes. probably you can do via 2 ways.

1.You can use Xcode after completion archive.You can able to see the option called **Upload to App store**. By doing this you can able to submit your app to iTunes connect.

2.**Application Loader** - Go to Xcode -> Open Developer tool -> Click Application Loader.

Finally submitted your app, You can check processing of submission your app to Tunes in your Build section.

> Note: You will receive mail for each & every actions in Itunes.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `fastlane` to automatic deploy in `iTC`.
Easy to setup and it can do many things automatically and faster.

https://fastlane.tools - main page

https://github.com/fastlane/fastlane/tree/master/deliver - thing that u need